# how to call a method in a servlet from another class

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I have to check if a user is using a mobile device.

I can do it with this code

```
String ua=request.getHeader("User-Agent");
```

In order to use `request` I need a servlet (do I?), so I created one and I put that code inside `doPost/doGet` method.

Since those are `void` methods, how can I get a return value to know if a user is using a mobile?

Probably my approach is not the right one.

My goal is to get from that servlet (assuming that I need just a servlet) a value that tells me if a user is using a mobile device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to use session and keep the `String ua` in the session

Either in the `doPost()` or in `doGet()`

```
String ua=request.getHeader("User-Agent");
Httpsession session=request.getSession();
session.setAttribute("ua",ua);
```

Now where ever you want to check just do

```
session.getAttribute("ua");
```

As long as the `session` exists, the value will be present.

Comment: To use 'request' i should use a servlet. Then the problem is how to call that servlet from my jsp page.

Comment: @MatteoDepasquali see there are any ways to call a servlet like in the form action="servlet" or in jquery button events or in ajax .It really depends on your requirement.

Comment: Yes, I know, but i can't call my servlet from the 'action' of a form. My servlet just checks the user agent, it doesn't print out anything on the screen. Anyway ill look into a way to call it, thank you man :)

Comment: @MatteoDepasquali If my answer is helpful then you may accept this answer,if you have any query then feel free to ask

Answer (score 1):

If you have multiple servlets and if you would need it for every request then consider creating a filter instead of a servlet. Where you can  do `String ua=request.getHeader("User-Agent");` and set it as a request param or session param. This may also help you in case going down the line you may need other header info from the HTTP envelope.

For a servlet , you will have to return it in the response or set it as a request/session param.

Answer (score 0):

> how can i get a return value to know if a user is using a mobile?

Write on `PrintWriter.write` method, it will display the text on response,

```
 if(isMobileAgent()){
 response.getWriter().write("User uses a mobile devices");
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Normally, other APIs or methods are called from the servlet's doPost or doGet methods.They act like the entry points of the incoming request. So you can parse the request and extract the necessary values as per your application needs and pass it to a processing API.

For the return value, I assume you are talking about the response. You can set the values in the response object.

Answer (score 0):

I assume the problem is like, you need to know the `User Agent` value from the JSP page?
Well, the request object is directly available in your page. 
In a script like

```
<%  String ua=request.getHeader("User-Agent") %>
```

can do the job.

Further, if you want the request object in java layer, somewhere deep inside your code flow, then its not the servlet you need to use, but persist the request object as method argument or a globally accessible member.